# How to show a loading gif while executing process?

Tags: c++, qt, qmovie

I want to show the user a loading gif while other window is executing. When my `graphdialog.ui` page executes, `showdb.ui` closes itself, so I didn't do movie->stop() step. But I am getting the error:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
> The process was ended forcefully.

What is the correct way to do this?

Here is the sample of my code:

**showdb.cpp**

```
void show_db::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QMovie *movie = new QMovie("qrc:/images/loadinggif.gif");
    this->ui->label->setMovie(movie);
    this->ui->label->show();
    this->ui->lineEdit->show();
    movie->start();

    GraphDialog grapghdialog(NULL,NULL);
    grapghdialog.setModal(true);  //sets second window here
    grapghdialog.exec();  //to show
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the gif **while** of **before** the opening a new dialog?

Comment: @scopchanov Yes. It takes a while to opening new dialog that's why I want to show gif while opening dialog.

Comment: Please check if [`QSplashScreen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#details) could meet your needs.

Comment: If your program crashes you should attach a debugger and find out where.